# How to print ascii banner on start of Django server?

Tags: python, django

How to print an ASCII art banner on the console when the Django Server is started with the commands:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Something similar to the below one:
[image]

Reference: Ajin Abraham MobSF https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/wiki/1.-Documentation

Is there a way to hook to the runserver command?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this banner in your `manage.py` may be ugly but will work without risk:

```
# near the end
if 'runserver' in sys.argv:
    print('This is my banner')
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
# end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I found the answer myself.

I added a `print` statement in the urls.py, which runs on server start.

**urls.py**:

```
...
print """ My Banner """
...
```